# How to Target all Textbox's within a Groupbox on a Window - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to setup a windows.resoruces style that targets all textbox's within all groupbox's (so it would not target textbox's that are not found within a groupbox)

I know I could use the x:key field, but was wondering if there was a way to target certain controls within controls for an entire window or application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a nested style for your TextBoxes in [Style.Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.resources.aspx) of GroupBox with [Style.TargetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype.aspx) but without [x:key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742804.aspx).

```
<Style TargetType="GroupBox">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            ...
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

One trick you could use is to define Textbox style without the x:key field. This one will apply to all the TextBoxes that do not have a Style specified.

Use this Style for the TextBoxes within the GroupBoxes by not using the Style Tag on these Boxes and for all other TextBoxes use a specific named Style by using the Style tag...